# If model is significant but some coefficients are not

Tags: regression

Suppose you have a linear model where the model is significant but some coefficients are not. How does one interpret the model when some coefficients are not significant?

Comment: You might have to explain a bit more about your model. Also, do you mean that some coefficients _are_ significant whilst others not?

Comment: This is normal situation. [Similar question](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/51583/3277) (you may ignore that the talk there is about stepwise selection)

Comment: Its a basic linear model with some coefficients significant at alpha = 0.05 and other coefficients not.

Comment: You may find the following related thread helpful as well: [how can a regression be significant yet all predictors be non-significant?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/14500/).

Answer (score 4):

If collinearity is not a major problem, you interpret "non-significant" coefficients exactly the same as you interpret "significant" ones, with confidence intervals.

Answer (score 1):

This may be a sign of high collinearity among your predictors/covariates---if the overall or omnibus test is statistically significant but none of the individual covariates are significant.  Check the condition indexes and their associated variance decomposition proportions.